# Create member alias based on a template parameter condition C++17

Tags: c++, templates, variables, metaprogramming, alias

So, I am trying to simplify the use of my generic classes and came across the following idea:

### The following struct is given:

```
template <size_t size>
struct Vector {
    std::array<float, size> data;

    float& x = data[0];
    float& y = data[1]; // Declare y only if size is > 0
    float& z = data[2]; // Declare z only if size is > 1
    float& w = data[3]; // Declare w only if size is > 2
};
```

Obviously, if I try to run the program like this, the array will throw an out of range exception.

Now is there a way to declare these aliases only if the condition (known at compile time) is given?

**I thought of something in the manner of std::enable_if:**

```
template <size_t size>
struct Vector {
    std::array<float, size> data;

    float& x = data[0];
    declare_if<(size > 0), float&> y = data[1];
    declare_if<(size > 1), float&> z = data[2];
    declare_if<(size > 2), float&> w = data[3];
};
```

Also, I would **prefer to not** let the class derive from another, or fully specialize the class.

Comment: afaik you can't do this without inheritance or specializing the class.

Comment: also please be mindful of your terminology: you don't have an `alias`. It is a simple non-static data member.

Comment: it may be worth noting that each reference variable needs at least as much memory as one element in the data array. (twice as much on 64-bit systems)

Comment: @Johan It's usually just a pointer in disguise

Comment: @PasserBy Yes, but on a 64-bit system a pointer is twice as big as a single precision float. My comment was just to remind that these aliases are not for free.

Comment: @SirHeadshot Out of curiosity, what do you need these aliases for?

Comment: @Johan it is nothing mandatory, it was just an idea to make the class more user-friendly in my framework, while also keeping it generic.

Comment: @SirHeadshot As I mentioned earlier, this will make each object of this type at least twice as big. If it was me, I would use the solution described by bolov. With optimization turned on any sane compiler will inline all calls to such a member function and you will gain the extra clarity without paying anything.

Comment: @SirHeadshot speaking of user-friendliness consider that making a class non-pod is not a decision to be taken lightly. Now you can no longer just memcpy arrays of `Vector` classes and can't serialise them trivially. The references take up a lot of space in the classes compared to the actual data. I think this trade-off is not actually worth it.

Comment: @Johan Yes that also makes the most sense to me now, thanks for the info.

Comment: @SirGuy I thought about that a lot, yes. The class was originally a simple struct, but since I want to implement it as part my math library, I added a complex constructor (which calls a private init method) to allow combinations of smaller vectors, floats and of course, the operators for a math vector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK you can do that and keep your syntax only with inheritance or specialization.

If you want to avoid that you need to change a bit the interface. You need to make `x`, `y`, `z`, `t` methods. Actually method templates:

```
template <size_t size>
struct Vector {
    std::array<int, size> data;

    template <std::size_t S = size, class = std::enable_if_t<(S > 0)>>
    auto x() -> int& { return data[0]; };

    template <std::size_t S = size, class = std::enable_if_t<(S > 1)>>
    auto y() -> int& { return data[1]; };

    template <std::size_t S = size, class = std::enable_if_t<(S > 2)>>
    auto z() -> int& { return data[2]; };

    template <std::size_t S = size, class = std::enable_if_t<(S > 3)>>
    auto t() -> int& { return data[3]; };  
};
```

```
Vector<2> v;

v.x();
v.y();
v.z(); // error: no matching member function for call to 'z'
```

Answer (score 2):

The most probable is to resort to specialization:

```
template <size_t size>
class Vector {
    std::array<float, size> data;

    float& x = data[0];
    float& y = data[1]; // Declare y only if size is > 1
    float& z = data[2]; // Declare z only if size is > 2
    float& w = data[3]; // Declare w only if size is > 3
};
template<> class Vector<0> {
    std::array<float, 0> data;
};
template<> class Vector<1> {
    std::array<float, 1> data;
    float &x = data[0];
};
```

(Note that I've changed size limits in the comments to not exceed array's bounds.)

Additionally, if you don't like the idea of full specialization, well, you'll need to introduce those members in the generic case anyway, but their default bindings can change:

```
template <size_t size>
class Vector {
    std::array<float, size> data;

    float& x = data[0];
    float& y = data[std::min(size - 1, 1)];
    float& z = data[std::min(size - 1, 2)];
    float& w = data[std::min(size - 1, 3)];
};
```

(If you're ok with x, y, z and w referring to the same array element.)

Comment: The problem with that seems to me, that I have to copy the whole class with all its functions in every specialization.
That would add really bad maintainability :/

Comment: @SirHeadshot The common way to avoid that is to (ab)use base classes. Make `Vector<2>` inherit from `Vector<1>` for example, and so on. But since you don't want to do that, it is as far as I know the only way to.

Comment: @Rakate1111 Thanks, the solution with the bind seems quite feasible.
Of course, actually enabling/disabling the declaration would be even better, since it prevents confusion, but I guess we can't have every little feature :D

Comment: @Rakete1111 while being the easiest, chained inheritance would cause memory overhead here: each specialization of Vector would hold shadowed `data`s of shorter specializations it inherits from. :\

Comment: @bipll you could just have the specialisation `1` define a single value `x` and have specialisation `2` (deriving from `1`) define a single value `y` and so on...

Comment: @SirGuy but what about data? It should be a template parameter-long array.

Comment: @bipll _should_? I don't see why it should exist if it doesn't have to. I was suggesting a new implementation from scratch, independent of the OP's current class. It may not suit, however, if the OP actually needs a member called `data` then it no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend approaching this a little bit differently than creating members that are references to other members (you have to manually implement the assignment operators for each one if you want your class to be assignable).

Why not some free functions that do the accessing for you?

```
template <std::size_t i, std::size_t size>
auto & get(Vector<size> & v) { return std::get<i>(v.data); }

template <std::size_t size>
auto & x(Vector<size> & v) { return get<0>(v.data); }

template <std::size_t size>
auto & y(Vector<size> & v) { return get<1>(v.data); }

//...
```

This will give a compile-time error if you try to access a member in a vector that has insufficient size

Answer (score 1):

If having functions returning reference instead of reference public member is an option, you can go with:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template<size_t size>
struct Vector
{
    std::array<float, size> data;

    template<size_t s = size, std::enable_if_t<s >= 1, int> = 0> float& x() { return data[0]; }
    template<size_t s = size, std::enable_if_t<s >= 2, int> = 0> float& y() { return data[1]; }
    template<size_t s = size, std::enable_if_t<s >= 3, int> = 0> float& z() { return data[2]; }
    template<size_t s = size, std::enable_if_t<s >= 4, int> = 0> float& w() { return data[3]; }
};
```

Comment: You will have hard failure as `size` is not a template parameter of the **method**.

Comment: @Jarod42 haha! true that! Fixed. Well, I've just seen bolov's answer. Should I delete that one?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers suggesting use functions rather than references to access. A reason not mentioned so far is that with the references you cannot enforce constness on the data: a `float&` in a const object is still modifiable *even if its referencing a const member variable*. Example derived from your code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t size>
struct Vector {

  Vector() { std::fill(data, data + 4, 0.0f); }

  float data[4];

  float& x = data[0];
  float& y = data[1]; 
  float& z = data[2]; 
  float& w = data[3]; 

  // read-write access
  float& getx() { return data[0]; }
};

int main()
{
  const Vector<4> v;

  //++v.data[0]; // compile error

  std::cout << v.x << std::endl;
  ++v.x; // modifies const through non-const ref!
  std::cout << v.x << std::endl;

  //++v.getx(); // compile error (member function enforces const)

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not declare a function template float& get() which you can std::enable_if based on size?

Comment: Even not get() but rather x(), y(), z() and w()! :)