# how to access a series of const variables as const array

Tags: c++

It's clear I can have:

```
const TYPE a();
const TYPE b();
const TYPE c();
```

and I can have

```
const TYPE all[] = {
  TYPE(),
  TYPE(),
  TYPE(),
};
```

But I would like to have both - direct and array access.

The memory layout should be the same anyway. The idea of a `union` comes to mind. Something along the lines of:

```
union FOO {
  struct index_t {
    TYPE a;
    TYPE b;
    TYPE c;
  } index;
  TYPE all[];
};

const FOO foo;
foo.index.a;
foo.all[0];
```

The naive approach is to just use references in the array

```
const TYPE a();
const TYPE b();
const TYPE c();

const TYPE all[3] = {
  a,
  b,
  c,
};
```

The questions is: Can I be sure these are only 3 instances or is there some copying going on turning them into 6?
Is there any memory overhead at all?

So which way would be the best to go?
Are both approaches feasible?

Note: Of course there is also the option to use an array of pointers - but the goal is to find a way with just references.

Comment: You can't have an array of references... so...

Comment: why no pointers? This seems to be a perfectly valid use case for pointers to me

Comment: btw while your code and the rest of the question could be c or c++, you cant have references in c (not to mention arrays of references)

Comment: The array of references compiles just fine.

Comment: If you are referring to the last version of `all` as an "array of references". Then you should be aware, it's not one. It's an array `TYPE` *values*. And `const TYPE& all[3]` is disallowed in standard C++.

Comment: So that implies the values are getting copied and I get 6 instances of TYPE?

Comment: of interest, tempted to close as dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404182/create-member-alias-based-on-a-template-parameter-condition-c17/48404634#48404634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like:

```
struct FOO {
    struct INDEX {
        const TYPE a; // Can even initialize in place, e.g. const int a = 8;
        const TYPE b;
        const TYPE c;
    };

    // From here on boilerplate
    Index index;

    FOO() : all{this} {}

    struct ALL {
        ALL(FOO* p): parent{p} {}

        const TYPE& operator[](unsigned index) {
            // Some pointer magic
            return *(static_cast<TYPE*>(static_cast<void*>(parent) + index * sizeof(TYPE)));
        }

        FOO* parent;
    };

    ALL all;
};
```

You'll have additional memory overhead of only the `parent` pointer (which is negligible if you plan to have many variables).  And there will also be runtime overhead - two static casts, one integer multiplication and one addition, but this will have the access syntax you aim and won't copy the variables.

Answer (score 1):

An array *is* a sequence of variables (technically objects, but the distinction is unimportant here). You don't need another one.

```
TYPE all[3]; // use std::array instead if you can
```

This is all what's *needed*. `const` is of no special importance here, add or remove it as reuired.

Now if you have a craving for syntactic sugar and *want* to alias `all[0]` as `a` etc, this is possible but this possibility is likely to come with a cost.

```
TYPE &a=all[0], &b=all[1], &c=all[2];
```

The compiler is likely to allocate storage for a, b and c, especially when they are members in a class (that's your cost). It may or may not optimise them away when they are static or automatic variables.

It should be emphasised that a, b and c are not *needed*. They simply provide alternate names for already existing objects `all[i]`.

Another way of achieving this is as follows

```
inline TYPE & a() { return all[0]; } // etc
```

This is unlikely to have any run-time cost, as compilers are very good at optimising such trivial functions away. The downside is that you need to write `a()` instead of `a`.

The union method, even if you manage to get it working for you, *is dangerous and not recommended* as it necessarily invokes undefined behaviour.